# Questions about derivatives with e and ln in them

Tags: calculus, derivatives

When taking the derivative of e^x I was under the impression it remained as e^x, but some books I've been reading have confused me.They show things like e^ -x and take the derivative as I mentioned before (i.e they leave it as e^ -x ) but they also take the derivative of the exponent. I had though the exponent was just left as is.

e.g e^ -x becomes (e^-x) * (  -1) I understand the -1 to have come from taking the derivative of the -x exponent but I am unsure why the have even taken the derivative of it as I thought the derivative of e^(any exponent) was just e^(any exponent)

Also when we have something like  e^-x *ln(2 + x^2)...I hope I have the parenthesis right there to illustrate my question)  I thought I'd use the product rule for the whole equation but use the chain rule for the ln part. I took the derivative of the inside of the parenthesis based on the ln I ended up with (1/(2+x^2))* 2x = (2x/2+ x^2).

But in the book it completely leaves the ln part alone . I am confused why they havent taken the derivative of it

Comment: If $f(x) = e^x$, you have to use the chain rule for $f(-x) = e^{-x}$.  Please share the full answer your book has, as it isn't clear.  In the product rule, you should leave the $\ln$ part alone for *one* of the terms.

Answer (score 2):

For any variable $u$ that is a differentiable function of $x$, the general rule is

$$ \frac{d}{dx} e^u = e^u \frac{du}{dx}.$$

That's it. Always. There is no exception, not even for $\frac{d}{dx} e^x$.
For $e^x$, the consequence of the general rule is

$$ \frac{d}{dx} e^x = e^x \frac{dx}{dx} = e^x$$

because $\frac{dx}{dx} = 1.$

Answer (score 1):

The derivative of the exponent in $e^{f(x)}$ is just application of the chain rule.

Taking the derivative of $e^{-x} ln(2 + x^{2})$ is indeed a product rule, and then chain rule. The resulting derivative is:

$-e^{-x}ln(2+x^{2}) + \frac{2xe^{-x}}{2 + x^{2}}$

Comment: arghh I had initially approached it by changing e^-x to -x ln e. I had thought when pulling the exponent down in front of e I had to add a ln. I take it that step is incorrect

Comment: That's an invalid move. You may be confused regarding the fact that $ln(a^{b}) = b ln(a)$ for $a, b > 0$.

Comment: thanks..so ln e^ -x would just give me -x then ?

Comment: Yes, that's right.